# Decoding a case class with `require`s in class body using circe throws an exception instead of returning `Left`

Tags: json, scala, circe

I have a case class with some logical constraints implemented as `require`s in the case class body. When trying to decode this case class from JSON representing a syntactically correct but logically invalid instance, the exception is actually thrown on the calling thread instead of being returned as a `Left` from `decode`.

Reproducing code snippet:

```
case class Foo(bar: String) {
  require(bar.length < 5)
}

object Sandbox extends App {
  import io.circe.generic.auto._
  import io.circe.parser._

  val foo1 = decode[Foo](""" {"bar":"abc"} """)
  println(s"foo1: $foo1")

  //expected: Left(IllegalArgumentException("requirement failed"))
  //actual: throws IllegalArgumentException("requirement failed")
  val foo2 = decode[Foo](""" {"bar":"abcdefg"} """) 
  println(s"foo2: $foo2")
}
```

Is it possible to have this exception returned as `Left` from `decode` without throwing? Any ideas / suggestions are welcome...

TIA

M.

Comment: Well `require` throws exceptions so that is it. Also in practice nobody uses it. - For this use case it would be better to use a [**refined**](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) type.

Answer (score 5):

Use refined to derive these codecs automatically with constraints.

Or if you want to validate JSON but not the constructor, you can always adjust codecs like

```
case class Foo(bar: String)
object Foo {
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Foo] = deriveDecoder[Foo].emapTry(foo =>
    Try(require(foo.bar.length < 5))
  )
}
```

Sometimes you can also use intermediate type for derivation and map over it:

```
case class Foo(bar: String) {
  require(bar.length < 5)
}
object Foo {
  // allows usage of derivation, especially if you would derive several typeclasses
  // and then adjust their behavior
  private case class FooHelper(bar: String)

  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Foo] = deriveDecoder[FooHelper].emapTry(helper =>
    Try(Foo(helper.foo))
  )
}
```

In general I would suggest not using `require`, especially in constructor and use a smart constructor instead.

```
sealed abstract case class Foo private (bar: String)
object Foo {

  def parse(bar: String): Either[String, Foo] =
    if (bar.length < 5) Right(new Foo(bar) {})
    else Left(s"Invalid bar value: $bar")

  def parseUnsafe(bar: String): Foo =
   parse(bar).fold(error => throw new Exception(error), foo => foo)

  private case class FooHelper(bar: String)

  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Foo] = deriveDecoder[FooHelper].emapTry(helper =>
    Try(parseUsafe(helper.foo))
  )
}
```